# Replace special characters in text field

Tags: apex

how can remove special character like "&,é,è,à,@,/,etc" and replace accents with the same letter without accent like é = e ?

I have a text field with lenght at 80.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [Edit] your question to add those details.

Comment: Or the referenced [Eliminating Unicode accents in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155370/eliminating-unicode-accents-in-apex)

Comment: I have try to find with RegEx, but i don't know how it's work, i think is like https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155370/eliminating-unicode-accents-in-apex
but the priority is for remove special character like '&, /, *'